# Browser showing page source only partially. Is there a way to get that source in full anyway?

Tags: browsers, page

Ranker.com has pages having button 'load more' at the bottom. Clicking on it adds new content to the page. However, when I select 'Show source' in my browser context-menu, no new content is there. I tried IE and Firefox. Saving page does not help in this regard either.

Is there a way to get full source of EVERY content a browser shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is to use Developer Tools in the browsers. Personally I like Chrome Dev Tools which can be opened with Ctrl+Shift+I, or right clicking the page and selecting "Inpect Element".

In the left panel you'll see the HTML. You can copy any section by right clicking on a tag and selecting "Copy HTML". (So to copy the entire page, right click on the `<html>` tag.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It appears that Firefox also has dev tools and it does the trick perfectly.